# Can I still earn coins in-game?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the new gym update, the defender bonus appears to have disappeared from the Shop. Is there still any way to collect coins through in-game activity, gym-related or otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can.  According to [this article](https://www.primagames.com/games/pokemon-go/tips/pokemon-go-how-collect-coins):

> - Place a Pokemon in a gym.
> - Pokemon must last at least one hour before being defeated.
> - <s>You'll earn one coin for every hour your Pokemon remains in the gym.</s>
> - Coins cannot be collected until the Pokemon is defeated.
> - <s>There is a maximum of 100 coins per day that can be earned.</s>

You must wait for your Pokemon to be defeated in a gym however to get the coins.  When a pokemons motivation reaches 0, it still must be defeated before it will return to you - giving you the coins.  [Niantic's support page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049347#bonus) states:

> You earn free PokéCoins for keeping your Pokémon on Gyms. The longer the Pokémon stay on the Gym, the more PokéCoins you earn. Be sure to give your Pokémon treats often to keep them on the Gym and maximize the PokéCoins you’ll earn. When your Pokémon’s motivation is reduced to zero, it will return to your collection, bringing back PokéCoins with it. You’ll receive a notification with the amount of PokéCoins earned when your Pokémon returns to you.

This seems to contradict when a pokemon's motivation reaches 0 it still must be defeated.  In fact, it contradict [Ninatic's own article](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004687-What-s-changing-in-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-) about the new changes:

> If a Pokémon’s motivation is **completely depleted in battle**, it leaves the Gym and returns to its owner the next time it is defeated.

---

**Edit:** Niantic updated the coin system due to complaints about how slow it was.  Currently, it appears to be about 1 coin ever 10 minutes.  [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j2s26/new_coin_amount/) contains some proof on this, and states:

> Update: There have now been 2 silent changes to coin accrual in the new system:
>
> 1. Coins are now granted 6x more frequently: in 10 minute increments, rather than hourly
> 2. Gym coin earnings are now capped at 50 coins/day

[This article](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2017/06/pokmongos-new-gyms-are-off-to-a-rocky-start/) also mentions the update:

> UPDATE: According to multiple user reports at The Silph Road, the coin payout has increased to be multiple times an hour, about 1 coin per 10 minutes of defence time at gyms — which is way more sensible!

The article linked at the top of this answer also has updated their page to reflect this:

> - Place a Pokemon in a gym.
> - Pokemon must last at least one hour before being defeated.
> - **You'll earn one coin for every 10 minutes your Pokemon remains in the gym.**
> - Coins cannot be collected until the Pokemon is defeated.
> - **There is a maximum of 50 coins per day that can be earned.**

Comment: The article says "defeated". Is this also true when a Pokemon returns to the trainer when losing all of its motivation overtime?

Comment: @Wondercricket lots of articles I'm seeing says "defeated" such as [this one](http://kotaku.com/the-new-pokemon-go-gyms-are-live-now-heres-what-you-ne-1796335788).  However, I did find [one article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-how-often-are-coin-bonuses-given-out/) that says "kicked out" (sounds like they mean defeated though).  I also thought that a pokemon with no motivation still has to be defeated before it leaves the gym as well? This [article states](http://heavy.com/games/2017/06/pokemon-go-what-happens-when-reaches-loses-all-zero-motivation/) so.

Comment: @TimmyJim These all seem to be 3rd party articles. Is there any official Niantic explanation (haven't seen any mention of coins their Updates page), or have you observed this firsthand in-game?

Comment: @yoozer8 revised answer with more sources.

Comment: I've observed a 50 coin max and a higher payout 1 coin per 10 minutes instead of 1 per hour

Comment: @ConradFrix That is because they updated the game again to change the coin system due to complaints.  Updated answer.

Comment: So every 10 minutes after the first hour or every 10 minutes after the first 10 minutes?  The update makes it a little confusing.

Comment: @Batophobia according to the first article I have linked in my answer, they state the Pokemon must be in the gym for at least one hour first.  Then every 10 minutes after that you get a coin.  Towards the  bottom of the article it mentions this.

Comment: @TimmyJim I am unsure about the part where your Pokemon needs to be in the gym for an hour before getting coins. Got a Pokemon that was returned to me 30 minutes after I put it in a gym, and I did receive my 3 coins.

Comment: @Isuka Since I don't actually play the game, I can't test for myself.  It seems resources on this specific issue is limited as well since the update is still too new.  Perhaps another question should be asked seeking a separate answer?

Comment: @TimmyJim It may be nice to have it as a separate question. If ever needed, [this graph](https://i.redd.it/v3r8pglvgg5z.png) sums up what you described too.

Comment: @TimmyJim I had a Pokèmon stay in a gym for 80 minutes and I got 80 coins, so it definitely counts from when you put it in.

Comment: How does the "maximum of 50 coins per day that can be earned" work? If my pokemon is there for 4 days, will it earn 50 coins per day and deliver 200 when it returns? Or will it accumulate a much larger number but only deliver 50 when returned (or fewer if another pokemon brought me coins the day it returns)?

Comment: @yoozer8 sounds like you have yourself a new question to ask :)