# No coins or notification: Do I need to do something to get earned coins?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just had a snorlax return from defending a gym for “1d 1h 33m”, but I didn't get any notification or coins. I only noticed when checking the gym badge list that my snorlax had been defeated. I checked my shop screen and my coin total hadn't changed though, and looking at my snorlax in my collection didn't do or show me anything. I can't find any buttons or indicators at all.

I *do* see entries in my journal for my snorlax returning (and for a rhydon that was defeated on the 23rd), but experimentally poking these entries didn't do anything.

Confused, I did some Googling and reading about the Gym Update after getting back home, but every source I've found (including [Can I still earn coins in-game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311730/can-i-still-earn-coins-in-game)) indicates that I *should* have received coins via a notification of some kind. I checked just now and have push notifications turned on in the Pokémon Go game settings, and my iPhone's notification centre settings has all permissions turned on for Pokémon Go, so I'm not sure where the notification went or where my coins went. There's nothing in the iOS pulldown notification screen for Pokémon Go.

Is there something else I need to do to enable coin-earning or a screen somewhere I need to use to go collect my coins? Is there a daily delay? Is it just a really unfortunate bug? (I know it's only 50 coins, but it does feel like there's little point in defending gyms while it's like this.)

Comment: This has happened to me as well. I had two knocked out on consecutive days but only the second gave me a push notification and told me my coin reward in game. Unfortunately, I don't remember how many coins I had before this, so I'm not sure if the first day's coins actually came in or not.

Comment: You didn't happen to reach the daily cap of 50 coins already have you? Seems like someone else on [GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/75498399) had something similar happen, but they seemed to have reached the cap already.

Comment: @TimmyJim I hadn't, no. Interestingly, I just had a different critter return and it *did* bring that max 50 coins with it, so that confirms that the earlier one today wasn't just me missing a control or option or something. Local midnight didn't change between them, though UTC midnight did. (However, I got no coins in the two days before the snorlax returned, so UTC midnight wouldn't explain the original lack of coins.)

Comment: It has been reported by some people that they didn't get coin rewards when the gym defender just ran out of CP by time instead of actually getting defeated. I guess the same bug happened to you.

Comment: @dly I thought you still had to be attacked to get knocked out of the gym, even if the motivation ran out from time?

Comment: @dly also I've had this happen to me and gyms are so active here that pokèmon never run out of motivation due to time. You're lucky if you can even find one to feed a berry to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, this could be a display bug where your Snorlax was in fact knocked out of the Gym *after* your other Pokemon that brought home the coins.

There is one way to find out exactly what happened: **The journal**. While it has a limited number of entries, there is a seperate limit for gym entries and it now displays the coins, too. If you check the journal from your profile page, there will be entries including date and time of all gym events, including *"Snorlax fought hard and returned"*.

If there's an entry for something else at the same date and earlier time, it's a display bug and your other Pokemon simply wasn't shown yet (and the coin total in the Shop apparently only updates once the notification at the top of the screen appears). If Snorlax did in fact return earlier than the other Pokemon, there must be something else going on.

By the way, you can check this many days later still. Due to the seperate entry limit for gym events, the end of the journal has many of these, usually dating back several days, even weeks if you weren't very active taking gyms.

Comment: Unfortunately, notifications do not have a guarantee on ordering, so think of it like receiving daily postal mail.  From this perspective, the out of order display is perhaps an artifact but not a bug.  Programming an in order notification system would require sgnificant overhead with little benefit.

Comment: I can't perfectly confirm it (this was the 28th of June and my Journal list of returning mons goes back to July 6 — so close!), but this seems most likely at this point, given the behaviour I saw. Also, I learned something new about the journal. :)

Comment: @Jerry I've never seen the journal entries display in a way that would make the coin payouts make no sense. So while it's probably possible their ordering is not guaranteed (although since they come with a timestamp, this issue should only occur for entries with the exact same date and time), the coin payouts seem to be based on ordering and I'd assume the earlier entry would feature the coins.

Comment: The journal entries are proper, but the notifications triggered by those entries do not have an in order guarantee.

Comment: Oh, now I get what you mean. Yeah, the notifications are pretty much random.

Answer (score -2):

Now that Pokemon gradually lose CP as they spend time in a gym, it is possible (likely) that your Pokemon returned after their CP was reduced to zero.

This would result in your Pokemon never having defended the gym, and thus you would receive no coins.

Comment: This is just not right. You get coins based on time. Your Pokémon doesn't earn coins based on battles. However, they won't be knocked out of a gym until someone battles them and defeats them, even if their CP has dropped to 1.

Answer (score -2):

"You can redeem a maximum bonus of 50 PokéCoins per day. Once you've reached the daily limit of 50 PokéCoins, you won't earn any more PokéCoins until the next day. If you have more than one Pokémon return from Gyms in a single day, the maximum bonus for the day is still limited to 50 PokéCoins. If a Pokémon returns after multiple days in a Gym, the maximum bonus for the day is still limited to 50 PokéCoins."

Via: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009533748-I-didn-t-receive-the-Defender-bonus

Comment: OP clearly is aware of this. There is something else going on here.