# How does the coin limit work?

Tags: pokemon-go

The new gym update [changes how coins are earned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/311731/32055), including a limit of 50 coins earned per day. How does this limit work? Is each pokemon limited to accruing 50 coins per day? Are all my pokemon limited to a collective 50 per day? My teammates keep feeding my Dragonite and she has been at the gym for almost a week; will she return with 50 coins for each day she was there? Fewer than 50 for the days I had other pokemon in the gym? Or will she accumulate vast sums of coins over the week, but only deliver me 50 (or fewer) when she comes back based on what I have collected from returning pokemon that day?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are limited to a total of 50 coins a day. That means your Pokémon are also limited to 50 coins total (since you can never get more than 50 in a single day). This means that once your Pokémon has been in a gym for 8 hours and 20 minutes (500 minutes), they are no longer accruing any coins for you.

For example, if you have 10 Pokémon in gyms for a week each, but they are all returned to you within the same day, you will only receive 50 coins. If they are kicked out one per day, then you will receive 500 coins total, 50 per Pokémon for 10 days.

Comment: Are you sure about the second paragraph? That sounds like a less than perfect solution. :-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt yes. It *is* a less than perfect solution. My Pokémon like to be returned in groups for some reason, so I've seen this happen multiple times now.

Comment: Let's hope for a change then.

Comment: @UliGerhardt it's a double-edged sword, really. On one hand, you could get a lot more coins than before, but it's out of your control since you only get coins when other people knock your Pokémon out of the gym (and other players can keep you in the gym)