# Does a Pokémon stuck in a gym over a full day collect coins for that day?

Tags: pokemon-go

As an example, let's say I put a Pokémon in a gym, say, Tuesday at noon, and it remains in the gym until Thursday at noon. Assuming I have nothing else in gyms collecting coins, would I get coins for this on Tuesday (where the Pokémon wasn't returned to me), or Wednesday (where it was neither placed in the gym nor returned); or would I only get coins for Thursday?

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but possible duplicate. Does https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/312186/32055 answer your question?

Comment: I had seen that question while writing this but someone had brought into question the marked answer's second paragraph, which pertained to my question. But since the answer is the same a week later I can assume that it hasn't been seriously refuted. In that case it may as well be marked as a duplicate. (Should I do this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only get coins when the Pokémon is returned to you and you are capped at 50 coins per day. Thus, you can never get more than 50 coins from any Pokémon that is returned to you.

For instance, I left an Arcanine in a gym for nearly 3 days. When it was returned to me, I received 50 coins. I did not receive any coins from Arcanine the two previous days.

Comment: That seems unrewarding. Thanks for your prompt answer.